# C# WCF Endpoint Response Stream

Tags: wcf, response, endpoint

I have an endpoint that connects to SQL and returns a result set to the client. The WCF Service sets the MaxReceivedMessageSize to a low value and therefore the endpoint does not return a result set.

I fixed the issue by increasing the MaxReceivedMessageSize value. However, I need to see just how much data is coming from the endpoint to the client.

I tried using Postman but that's not working. What's the best way to capture what the endpoint is returning to the client?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect or modify the incoming or outgoing messages across a WCF client by implementing a [System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and inserting it into the client runtime.

[Inspect messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client?redirectedfrom=MSDN) not only implements the inspector on the client side, but also manipulates the endpoint behavior.